# Compilation process of programs using C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

Say the following codes are written for the same purpose.The rest of the code of the programs are the same.

code1

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> vector1;
vector<int> vector2;
vector<int> vector3;
vector<int> vector4;
```

code2

```
 #include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> vector1;
vector<short> vector2;
vector<char> vector3;
vector<bool> vector4;
```

now which one is better (let in terms of executable size) ? (hint : consider the executables)
I compared the assembly result given by g++ -S .
Surprisingly the number of lines of the second program is 1778 , the first one is 630. Which means the first one is better.
To reason this behavior,  I looked for a good resource for "how the template based programs are compiled" but I couldn't find one.
How the programs that use templates are compiled in to assemblies by the compiler ? Do you have a good resource ?
(this is not a homework,but a self study problem given in my workplace.Should you feel not to give an answer at least direct me to a good resource)

Comment: Define "better": the two pieces of code are not equivalent.

Comment: How can we pick the better one if: #1 we don't actually have a goal in mind; #2 the examples produce no interesting results; #3 the examples *do different things*. The better one is probably the one that does what you want because... well, because it does what you want.

Comment: edited the question. actually my main problem was the reason for that behavior.

Comment: Read this: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html (explains both what happens and why).

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all if 90% of the increase would be due to `vector<bool>`. The three other vectors are simple wrappers around a `T[]` array, but `vector<bool>` is packed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour you find is not surprising at all. The compiler generates as many classes as it needs using the template. In your first example it only needs to generate one (`vector<int>`), while in your second it needs to generate four. Of course, this generates more code.

As for the question of which one is better: the one that better serves its purpose, of course. But only you are in a position to know that.